# What are the query browsers for DB2?

Tags: database, db2

What are the query browsers for DB2 e.g Database Administrator(Data Studio), Toad for DB2 etc? I worked with them but are there more ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a list of browsers in Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools#General

and look at "Other" column. You will see which tools work with DB2.

The popular ones are:

- Toad for DB2 http://www.toadworld.com/products#ibm-db2
- SQuirreL http://www.squirrelsql.org
- SQL Maestro http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/db2/maestro/
- Altova DatabaseSpy http://www.altova.com/databasespy.html
- Embarcardero PowerStudio for DB2 http://www.embarcadero.com/products/db-powerstudio-for-db2

Or

- IBM Data Studio (Free) http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/
- Technology Explorer (from IBM, on PHP) http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/
- Control Center (Deprecated, included in IBM Data server client)

Comment: A good new open source SQL client with Db2 support is Plotly Falcon. https://plot.ly/free-sql-client-download/

Answer (score 11):

I've recently discovered DBeaver (http://dbeaver.jkiss.org) and I love it.
Runs on Win and Linux (on Centos7 I just unpacked an archive and ran executable), it's open source and without need of external driver it has connected to DB2 server right away. Same for PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server. 
Not sure how it compares with other in feature set though, but user experience compared to previously used Squirrel is amazing.

Comment: Outstanding!  This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: I am having trouble making connection in this tool. Can you please help me for DB2?

Comment: I wish this answer had been selected. DBeaver is the only one that's truly free and open source that will download the needed drivers automatically (at the click of a button)  and work right out of the box.  The majority of the answers in the selected answer are either not actually free, require difficult setup, or plain do nor work with db2. DBeaver has amazing search capability,  SQL formatting, fully customized morphing queries to delimited lists, etc.  It's objectively the only real choice and the cream of the crop.

Answer (score 2):

I find [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) to be outstanding even when compared to many native tools.

[image: DbVisualizer Features]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the IBM data studio among the free tools. It lets you

- Manipulate(Create , modify, execute) stored procedures
- See explain plans - run performance analysis
- Let you open unlimited connections which some of the free tools doesn't let you.

Also, it's based on eclipse framework, so if you are already using eclipse its almost a breeze to learn. Toad freeware is also cool, however the freeware has a licensing limitation of max 5 per enterprise.

Also, check the [latest IBM data studio download](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/)