# What are some SQL clients with a graphical query designer..?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Another user asked the similar question, [What are the query browsers for DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381345/what-are-the-query-browsers-for-db2).

But I would like to ask: what are some SQL browsers with a graphical query designer? Like the other user, I'm also using DB2, but most generic or open-source clients can connect to any SQL server, so I'll assume if there are any with a GQD, I'll be able to use it with DB2.

The vintage of our DB2 server and AS400 is v5/v6 and unlikely to be upgraded any time soon, and I find the included IBM SQL client to be primitive to the point of useless. The other clients I've tried are DBeaver, Toad, and Squirrel. I got DBeaver to work with our server, but other two I could not (yet). It's very nice and I'm happy to stick with it, but alas it does not have a GQD.

I understand many DBAs feel a GQD is an impediment to advanced query design, and I agree. However, it can be a useful tool for visualizing and building sub-sections of large queries, especially joins and weird logic. I find the most useful method is to design some or all of a query graphically, and then switch to pure SQL and clean it up.

Comment: Off Topic. Search for SQL query builder jdbc.  Evaluate IBM Data Studio (free download), Aqua Data Studio etc.

Comment: Ha..!! Thanks. Sort of. I searched as you suggested, but then had a sudden inspiration to switch the view to Google Images. And behold...I can see pictures or which clients have a GQD. Also, I didn't realize IBM Data Studio was free, which is the focus of my search. Aqua is not free.

Comment: Also, if my question is off-topic, why isn't the other guy's question that I refer to in mine..???

Comment: It's off topic too.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [AQT Advanced Query Tool](http://querytool.com)

It has a graphical query builder and can be recommended - it supports Db2 for iSeries

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out.